# Drag and Drop of User Story do not "really" save one specific state "in progress"

Tags: azure-devops, drag-and-drop, state, azure-devops-server-2019

we have a Board with User Storys and the states as follows: new, is processed, on hold, preparatory work necessary, pending input, canceled and final.

Process definition / settings:
New relates to "Proposed"
on hold, is processed, preparatory work necessary, pending input and canceled relate to "In Progress" and final to "Completed".

When we (admins or "normal" members / contributors, we all have basic licence) drag a User Story to "is processed" via board and **only** in this case the state not really saves. I build a Power BI Report on an analytical view of the project and some stories seem to be not assigned to a state, they are shown without a state.

When i open the user story in DevOps i can see, that the Story has the state "is processed", BUT the circle symbol to the left is not filled in completely, it only has a colored frame (I hope you understand, what i try to describe). When i go into the story directly and save the story with this state, then it works. The circle symbol is then filled in completey and the power bi report shows this story with the state "is processed".

Any other status can be changed via drag and drop without open the story directly and change & save the status there.

I hope, you can help us.

If you need more information please let me know.

Regards

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Problem found and fixed :-)

A state was assigned in the background that no longer existed. It was just a small typo "is processed" and "Is processed". Now column matches to the correct state. None of our team saw this little cause.